# A question about "It's worth it" in a text

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please read the following paragragh and answer my question.

My job is to write programs for games. I work closely with other developers and discuss things a lot. I decide how to move the characters, how to get points, where to include sound effects, and so on. And I need to figure out what's wrong when a bug is found. Whatever the bug is, I have to fix it. I check every step and correct the problems. It takes a lot of time and energy, but (1)it's worth (2)it to develop a perfect game.

So my question is, what does each of the first (1)it and second (2)it refers to in the text? Someone tells me that the second (2)it refers to fixing bug while another tells me that the second (2)it refers to "a lot of time and energy". It makes me confused.
Thank you.

Comment: Hey qtwqwd, Armand's given you a correct and useful answer, but if you want more perspectives, or have similar questions (now or in the future), you should ask on our sister site, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first *it* is the formal subject, just like in

> It's raining
>
> It's nice to see you

The second *it*, I believe, doesn't really stand for anything. *worth it* is an idiom, meaning that "a lot of time and energy", "effort", etc. are duly compensated.  Because of this, one of your friend tells you that it stands for "a lot of time and energy". Because we can use phrases like

> It's worth fixing the bug

It makes your other friend say that it stands for "fixing the bug".